# How to verify all the dependencies are installed in sagemaker?

Tags: serverless, amazon-sagemaker

I am creating an sagemaker endpoint and loading a pretrained model from an s3 bucket. the model -> model.tar.gz file has directory structure as documented here, https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/frameworks/pytorch/using_pytorch.html#model-directory-structure

```
model.tar.gz/
|- model.pth
|- code/
  |- inference.py
  |- requirements.txt  # only for versions 1.3.1 and higher
```

I have put few dependencies in requirements.txt, is there a way to verify that all the dependencies were installed correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to get access or SSH into the machine that's running your deployment. So, one way is to assert the versions of your dependencies in the `model_fn` inside "inference.py" something like below.

if your requirements.txt looks like this:

```
numpy==1.20.3
pandas==1.3.4
```

get the versions and assert them in `model_fn like below:

```
import os

### your other code ###

def model_fn(model_dir):
    # assuming you have numpy and pandas
    assert os.popen("python3 -m pip freeze | grep -E 'numpy|pandas'").read() == 'numpy==1.20.3\npandas==1.3.4\n'
    ### your other code ###
    return xxxx

### your other code ###
```